# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68 - Fresh Installation

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I have a Laravel project for more than one year and everything worked well in my env.
A week ago I have installed a new HD and need to install everything again and the laravel stops to work.

Anothers developers in my team are working with the project and I've check the others env and everything looks like the same.

When I try to login in my system (form post) I got this error: **"TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68"**

Note: I have read a lot of topics and try a lot of solutions and nothing is working.

Note 2: The "storage/framework/session" folder have permission to write and I have a lot of session files there.

Note 3: In my web server everything is ok also. So I think this is not a application problem, but a enviroment problem. (the biggest problem is: I don't know what is the env problem =/

Do anyone know what is going on?

My enviroment:

**OS: Mac OS High Sierra 10.13**

**PHP: 7.1.7**

**Laravel: 5.4.17**

Some files that the other topics told about:

.env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:kYGq9r2jM9FwWXg19ip+MioiHmfkXn/xD708KqBYAb4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=healthsangel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

Login Blade:

```
    @extends('layouts.login')

@section('content')
<div class="container wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.5s" data-wow-duration="2s">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="bg-white login_content login_border_radius col-md-6 login_background">
            <form class="form-horizontal form_margin" role="form" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="POST" action="{{ url('/dashboard') }}">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-md" id="loggedUserUid" name="loggedUserUid">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3 class="text-center">
                       <img src="{{asset('/img/logo_name.png')}}" height="200" width="200">
                    </h3>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control  form-control-md" id="email" name="email" border-width= "medium" placeholder="Usuário ou email" required autofocus>
                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <!--</h3>-->
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">                              
                        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-md" id="password"   name="password" placeholder="Senha" required>
                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center hiddenStyle" id="wrong_credentials">
                    <span class="help-block text-center error-text">
                        <strong id="error_text">Usuário ou senha incorretos!</strong>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-center hiddenStyle" id="loading_view">
                    <span class="help-block text-center error-text">
                        <img src="/img/rolling.gif" width="5%"></img>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:2px !important">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <a href="/register" class="btn btn-block signup_button">Cadastrar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:2px !important">
                        <input type="submit" onClick="doLogin()" value="Login" id="loginButton" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-large login_button loading_button">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">                               
                        <h6 class="text-center">
                            <b>
                            <a align="center" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}" class="custom-control-description forgottxt_clr"><u>Esqueceu a senha?</u></a>
                            </b>
                        </h6>                                
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">                               
                        <h6 class="text-center">
                        <b class="gray_text">
                            Ao entrar você está aceitando o nosso 
                            <a align="center" href="{{ url('http://hangel.com.br/termos-de-uso') }}"  target="_blank" class="custom-control-description error-text"><u>Termo de Uso e Política de Privacidade</u></a></b>
                        </h6>                                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

config/session.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
    | cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
    | correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
    |
    */

    'store' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

];
```

routes/web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@index');

Route::post('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');

Route::get('/patients', 'PatientsController@index');
Route::get('/favorites', 'PatientsController@favorites');
Route::get('/doctors', 'DoctorsController@index');
Route::get('/pontuation', 'PontuationController@index');
Route::get('/editProfile', 'EditProfileController@index');

Route::get('/patientDetails/{uid}', 'PatientDetailsController@index');
Route::get('/patientDetails', 'PatientDetailsController@openPatientDetails');

Route::get('solicitations', 'SolicitationsController@index');
Route::get('alerts', 'AlertsController@index');

Route::post('/inviteDoctor', 'InviteDoctorController@index');

Route::post('/registerAdmin', 'RegisterController@registerAdmin');
Route::get('/registerAdmin', 'RegisterController@registerAdmin');

Route::post('/dashboardAdmin', 'DashboardController@dashboardAdmin');
Route::get('/dashboardAdmin', 'DashboardController@dashboardAdmin');
```

I just found that my token is different from session token. Why this is harppening? The print follows:
[image: My token x Session token]

Comment: Have any server configs changed? Try to delete vendor folder, run composer install and php artisan view:clear

Comment: No, there is not configs changed in the serve. I did like you ask me, but still not working =/.

Answer (score 0):

May this command help you:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: I've checked and the method "GET" works, but the post still not working. So weired.

Comment: @rodrigo-xavier post return TokenMismatchException?

Comment: Yes, the post returns TOkenMismatchException. Now, I just find that the token passed by the post is different from session. That's why got this error. But I don't know why. Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED my problem!!!

It a mix of problems. To solve, I did those five steps:

1. `composer update`
2. `chmod 755 storage/frameworks/sessions`
3. `rm -rf storage/frameworks/sessions/*`
4. `php artisan config:cache`
5. Restarted again and everything works!

Thank you everyone that help me. Hope can help another devs with this weired problem.